# Serving static big images rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cdn

I'm currently serving all images in my app from CDN. Images are located at `app/assets/images` folder in my rails app.

And after the application is precompiled, all the assets are uploaded to CDN, and it works great.

However there are dozen of large image files which are almost never changing, mostly served to users while they're not logged in, as a part of carousel or something else.

So in case that a new application version would come out, those static images would be re-uploaded again, and users would have to re-download them but they never change, so it's kind of redundant, and for large size it's not really meaningless.

My idea was to put the images in the `vendor/assets/images`, and directly load them in my app, without the suffix/hash generated by the app. Ex: if you have image in your app named `2.jpg`, after the assets have been precompiled it might have been saved to CDN as `2-49d87927b61510021a3cd0a895502625.jpg` or something along that.

So I would be now adding this above image as :

```
= image_tag('2.jpg', alt: '')
```

But since I have this line in my `assets.rb` initializer :

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
```

The image `2.jpg` will be precompiled with hash on production environment.

So how can I make use of this image that is not precompiled with hash on prod, but rather remained the same?

If I put :

```
= image_tag('2.jpg', alt: '')
```

It should render as `<image src='http://CDN_URL/assets/2.jpg' />` and not as `<image src='CND_URL/assets/2-23123dasdasdsadsasad21312.jpg' />` because this one is under `vendor/assets/images` I still want my regular images `app/assets/images` to be served with hash. Is this possible? and how?

**Update :**

In my development environment I don't server static assets. Just a regular development config. But I would prefer solution that works for both(DEV and PROD) environments.

**Update II:**

Looks like `%img{src: 'assets/2.jpg'}` loads the file from the `vendor/assets/images` which is fine.

Still the other issue persist, when I precompile the assets and when I have `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)` in the `assets.rb` initializer the image with hash i.e `2-32131dasdaeasee12eda.jpg`

If I remove the `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)` from the config, no image `2.jpg` is copied to `public/assets`, and therefore not copied to CDN.

Comment: why not use `<img src="yourcdn.com/images/1.png">` ? for your static images. 
image_tag will always append md5 mask(or whatever you use)

Comment: @Avdept `%img{src: 'images/2.png'}` doesn't even work on localhost. In the development where I don't server static assets

Comment: shouldnt it be like `'/images/2.png'` ?

Comment: @Avdept no, actually `%img{src: 'assets/2.jpg'}` works on the localhost. But still another part of the problem, when I precompile there is no image file for `2.jpg` copied to public assets folder.

Comment: From Rails docs _When the file contents change, the filename is also changed._ So if your image did not change than it will not generate new file hash at precompiling

Answer (score 1):

The premise for your problem is not correct:

> So in case that a new application version would come out, those static images would be re-uploaded again, and users would have to re-download them but they never change, so it's kind of redundant, and for large size it's not really meaningless.

The hashed fingerprint is the MD5 of the file content.  If the file hasn't changed, then neither will the fingerprint.  There's no reason you need to make an exception for large files - the system should work exactly as you want without customizing the process.

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow This is the whole point of fingerprinting. The digits added aren't arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to static serve files without the finger printing or any of the other benefits of the asset pipeline, then  **don't use the asset pipeline**.

Put your files in `/public`.